# Put colorbar between title and maps - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, colorbar

I'm trying to put my discrete matplotlib color bar between my maps and my title, but I cannot seem to get it working.

Here's my code:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
map = Basemap(projection='mill', lon_0=0, llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=50, ax=ax)
map.drawcoastlines(color='black', linewidth=0.5)
map.drawcountries(color='black', linewidth=0.5)
map.fillcontinents(color='#ebebeb', lake_color='white')

RR = [254, 252, 251, 222, 165]
GG = [229, 174, 106, 45, 15]
BB = [217, 145, 74, 38, 21]

colors = np.c_[RR, GG, BB] / 255
my_colormap = clr.ListedColormap(colors)
VariableLimits = np.array([0, 5, 10, 50, 100])
bounds = np.append(VariableLimits, 1000)
norm = clr.BoundaryNorm(bounds, len(colors))

sc = map.scatter(x, y, c=merged_df['frp'], cmap=my_colormap, norm=norm, alpha=0.05, s=0.01)

# Création de la colorbar avec les valeurs correspondantes aux couleurs
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, ticks=VariableLimits, boundaries=bounds, pad=0.1, ax=ax, orientation="horizontal")
cbar.ax.set_title('(mm)', size=8)
cbar.ax.tick_params(left=False, right=True, labelleft=True, labelright=False)


plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0.1, top=0.9)
aujourd_hui = datetime.now()
date_formatee = aujourd_hui.strftime("%d %B %Y")
title = plt.title(f'Suivi des incendies dans le monde\nau {date_formatee}', fontproperties=brown_bold)
title.set_fontsize(25)
plt.annotate('Source : Fire information for resource management system (FIRM), NASA', (0, 0), (0, -10), fontsize=10, xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points', va='top',fontproperties=brown_regular)

# Affichage de la carte
plt.show()
```